# Add new objects prev and next to Entity Post

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm trying to find a way that can produce less **request** when visiting a Post Entity and be able to get the **previous and next Post** from that **Entity**, right now what I do in the same view with Twig is get it in the following way.

```
{% set next = next(post) %}
{% set prev = prev(post) %}
```

Twig Extension

```
public function next($post){

        $nextPost = $this->em->getRepository('App:Post')->createQueryBuilder('b')
            ->where('b.id > :id')->setParameter('id', $post->getId())
            ->andWhere('b.visible = :visible')->setParameter('visible', true)
            ->orderBy("b.id","asc")
            ->setMaxResults(1)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getOneOrNullResult();


        return $nextPost;
    }
    public function prev($post){

        $prevPost = $this->em->getRepository('App:Post')->createQueryBuilder('b')
            ->where('b.id < :id')->setParameter('id', $post->getId())
            ->andWhere('b.visible = :visible')->setParameter('visible', true)
            ->orderBy("b.id","desc")
            ->setMaxResults(1)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getOneOrNullResult();


        return $prevPost;
    }
```

There would be some way to get it with **less mysql requests**, and adding it to the Post object in this particular way.

```
{{post.prev.title}}
{{post.next.title}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I can think of, is storing a reference to the prev/next object in the entity. Then you can use joins to fetch them.

You could also write a complex query, that loads your current entity and also performs both of your queries as subqueries or with UNION to fetch all 3 of them at the same time, but I think that would become quite unwieldy.

I would not worry about these 3 queries though. Merging it into one big query will make it harder to read and debug and I doubt the performance gain will be even noticable. Unless you currently notice an impact on performance from these queries, optimizing it will just waste time you could spend on something else. You can do some performance analysis, i.e. by investigating bottlenecks in the performance and query tabs in the profiler toolbar.